# PHP, How to prevent people from downloading my file?

Tags: php, html, security

How do I prevent people from downloading my file from going to its URL (i.e. `mywebsite.com/file.csv`)?

This is my current code. I'm trying to make people fill out a form before they can view the file:

```
<?php
$box2 = $_POST['box2'];
$box1 = $_POST['box1'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$glide = $_POST['glide'];
$data = $box1. ',' .$box2. ',' .$type. ',' .$glide;

$file = "file.csv";

file_put_contents($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
print "<h1 align=center>test</h1>";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="prevensjon.html">Go back</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put "file.csv" file out side of the public or www folder on hosting and call it

Answer (score 0):

You should put the file out of the root folder of your website (i.e. move it outside of `/var/www/html` / `htdocs` / etc) so that visitors cannot access it.

Next, you can get the file's data using PHP. Try

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents("/var/www/myfile.csv"));
```

to get the file's data and encode it into Base64 so that it can be quickly transferred.

Now, all you need to do is provide a link that forces the download of this file using a Data URL:

```
<a href="data:text/plain;base64,<?=$data?>" download="name.csv">Download</a>
```

This will put the raw contents of the file into the URL of the link, and the `download` attribute means that the file will always be downloaded, and will have the name provided (i.e. it will be downloaded as a file called `name.csv` when the link is clicked).

Now, you just need to ensure that the link is not generated until you want it to be. This can be done with basic PHP.

### Further Reading

- [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)
- [`base64_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

Comment: What if someone can get to the link?

Comment: @Progrock You do not generate the link until the user has authed / filled out the form / etc. Just put a PHP `if` statement around it so it won't be shown to other users

Comment: May be issues if the csv data grew large.